# Google Analytics-like module for Drupal site behind firewall?

Tags: drupal, module, google-analytics

Anyone know how to use Google Analytics for a Drupal-powered company intranet site behind our firewall?

and/or

Anyone know of a good analytics-style module for Drupal that can tell us things like visitor browser/versions, OS, monitor size, etc. ? Pretty graphs and charts nice but not required. Or at the least a recipe for rolling our own thru views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll tackle the firewall issue by saying- set up a stats package on an internal web server. There are a few Drupal modules that provide the connective tissue.

[Piwik](http://drupal.org/project/piwik) might still be a little raw, but it has good screenshots. It is sort of a self-hosted Google Analytics. [FireStats](http://drupal.org/project/firestats) has popped up since I last checked into this. Also available is [BAWStats](http://drupal.org/project/bawstats) which operates by log analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look @ [mint](http://haveamint.com/)  it may reside with your drupal files .......
it is my alternative for Google Analytics with local intranets.

EDIT : there it's the [Mint](https://www.drupal.org/project/mint) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> Provides basic integration with Mint, a proprietary traffic logging and statistics tool.

Answer (score 1):

[WebTrends](http://www.webtrends.com/Products/Analytics/Software.aspx) can do that -- but it's *not* cheap.